# Use modal to take user checkbox input and return data back to parent component

Tags: react-native

I have a `Newevent` class component which takes several user inputs. One of them is an array of user ids called access list and the rest is text input. Here is the code I am thinking about:

```
export default class NewEvent extends React.Component {

    state = {
        name: '', 
        access_list: [],
        modalVisible: false
        };
triggerModal() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        display: true
      }
    });
  }

render() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder='Name'
                autoCapitalize="none"
                placeholderTextColor='white'
                onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('name', val)}
            />


            <Button 
               onPress = { () => this.triggerModal() }
               title = "Open Modal"
               color = "orange">
            </Button>
            <DisplayModal
              visible={this.state.modalVisible}

            />

            <Button
            title='Save'
            onPress={this.save}
            />
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

In `DisplayModal.js`, it is a function component to display a series of checkbox allowing user to check which user he wants to include in access list:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Modal, View, Image, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'

const DisplayModal = (props) => (
  <Modal visible={ props.display } animationType = "slide" 
         onRequestClose={ () => console.log('closed') }>>
    <View>
      <CheckBox
        title='Click Here1'
        checked={this.state.checked}
      />
      <CheckBox
        title='Click Here2'
        checked={this.state.checked}
      />
    </View>
  </Modal>
)
```

Any recommendation about constructing `DisplayModal.js` to return the user's selection?

Comment: Do you want to send state from `DisplayModal` to `NewsEvent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the problem but I think that you want to send states from `DisplayModal` to `Newsevent` for that purpose at least there are two methods:

1- Using redux which is a little(or too) complicated. you can read [the documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react).

2- use a `props` which is a function that returns data from the child component to the parent.
for example:

```
export class DisplayModal extends Component {
  state = {
    item1: false,
    item2: false
  };
  _updateState = item => {
    this.setState({ item: !this.state[item] });
    // use the getState props to get child state
    return this.props.getState(this.state);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        visible={props.display}
        animationType="slide"
        onRequestClose={() => console.log("closed")}
      >
        >
        <View>
          <CheckBox
            title="Click Here1"
            checked={this.state.checked}
            onPress={() => this._updateState("item1")}
          />
          <CheckBox
            title="Click Here2"
            checked={this.state.checked}
            onPress={() => this._updateState("item2")}
          />
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

and use the `getState` props to get user's selections:

```
<DisplayModal getState={(items)=> this.setState({userSelections:items}) />
```

after each action on `DisplayModal` i.e on checkbox press, `_updateState`  call the function the function in `props` and in your example, the function gets data from the child and update the parent state.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on method of `_updateState`? like when this method is called and how it returns the user selections. This is where I stuck.Thanks.

Comment: I Just updated my answer, please check that and feel free to ask any question about that.